# in c#, Why this code work as by reference? I intended to use as by value

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I'm trying to make a list of class as history.

So list of a class was declared like this.

```
private List<SearchHistoryItem> SearchHistoryList;
```

SearchHistoryItem is a class that have two property.

```
public DataTable SearchResultDataTable;
public SearchCondition SearchCondition; // this is another class.
```

Whenever this method is called, I make temporary 'SearchHistoryItem', copy from current instance and add to the list.

```
public void GetMainDataAsConditionMethod()
{
    SearchHistoryItem tmpItem = new SearchHistoryItem();
    tmpItem.SearchCondition = CurrentSearchCondition;
    tmpItem.SearchResultDataTable = MainChartDataTable;

    SearchHistoryList.Add(tmpItem);
}
```

I think there is no reason to copy datas by reference. But when this code is running, 
every items in the List 'SearchHistoryList' have same values of CurrentSearchCondition and MainChartDataTable.
I checked 
How can I solve this to be copied by value?

Comment: Well, `tmpItem.SearchResultDataTable = MainChartDataTable;` just creates another reference to the exact same `DataTable`. Doing anything on one reference will be reflected in all references, of course. When you want an independend copy of your table, you have to **create a new one**: `tmpItem.SearchResultDataTable = new ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign an object (such as a List) to a variable, you assign a reference. When you do anything to the object on one reference, all references will show the change, because they are just *references* to the same object.

What you want to do is copying the list before you pass it on, such as

```
tmpItem.SearchResultDataTable = new List<...>();
tmpItem.SearchResultDataTable.AddRange(MainChartDataTable);
```

Note: This only creates a [shallow copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copying#Shallow_copy), not a deep copy. If you want a deep copy, would have to clone each object in the list individually.